# Processing P3D Animation leaving artifacts behind

Tags: processing

I am trying to make a spinning cube in Processing's P3D with this code:

```
int sizes = 500;
int rotation = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  lights();
  translate(sizes/2, sizes/2, 0);
  rotateY(rotation * (PI/180));
  rotateX(rotation * (PI/180));
  background(0);
  box(sizes/2);
  rotation = (rotation + 1);
}
```

When I run it the cube does spin as I wanted, but there are strange 'artifacts' (for lack of a better name) left behind its edges.

[image]

What causes this issue, and can it be solved?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see any "artifacts". Do you've screenshot?

Comment: Here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ReBwkfhsHVjBjGjQruj5E36MiyYiP0YV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue. What is your OS? It seems the the background is not cleared properly. What happens if you move `background(0);` to the first line in `draw()`

Comment: Nope. It just changed the look of the artifacts. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked. Maybe instead of using backround(0), set every pixel to black like the background function does manually.

```
int sizes = 500;
int rotation = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  fill(255);
  lights();
  translate(sizes/2, sizes/2, 0);
  rotateY(rotation * (PI/180));
  rotateX(rotation * (PI/180));

  loadPixels();
  for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) pixels[i] = color(0);

  box(sizes/2);
  rotation = (rotation + 1);
}
```