# Processing P3D not rendering properly

Tags: animation, processing, rendering

I tried to make a simple 3d spinning cube in processing.

```
int size = 100;
float angle = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  lights();
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  rotateY(angle);
  rotateX(angle);
  background(0);
  box(size);
  angle+=0.05;
}
```

When i run it, i got a nice spinning cube but there is some problem in rendering.

Found a similar thread with no answer:-
[Processing P3D Animation leaving artifacts behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881772/processing-p3d-animation-leaving-artifacts-behind)

[Image Depicting the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB5s6.png)

[image]

Comment: What is your operating system? Do you use the most recent version of [processing](https://processing.org/download/)? (version 3.5.3)

Comment: I am on Windows-10 and yes i am using the latest version of processing.

Comment: That's wired. Definitely there is an issue, because you're the 2nd with the same problem. But it is a very basic program and I can't reproduce the behavior. Did you try to update the graphics card driver? Processing uses OpenGL under the hood.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes there is something really weird, my graphics drivers were up to date, i will try this on some other device and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Although I could not found the reason for this weird effect. But here is a quick hack which worked out for me.

Instead of using the background function to fill the background, simply draw a filled rectangle every frame.

```
int size = 100;
float angle = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  //black
  fill(0);
  //rectangle to fill the canvas
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  lights();
  fill(255);
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  rotateY(angle);
  rotateX(angle);
  box(size);
  angle+=0.05;
}
```